# VBA javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

I been trying to adapt code to get this working but with no success. I need to submit as guest the following webpage:

```
<div class="lotusBtnContainer">
<input type="submit" class="lotusBtn" value="Access as a Guest"onclick="javascript:asGuest();">
<input type="submit" class="lotusBtn" value="Log in and Access" onclick="javascript:asUser();">
<span class="lotusAction"> &nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

This is what I have so far, since the button doesn't have an ID I'm not sure how to address it:

```
Dim IntExpl As Object
Set IntExpl = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IntExpl
      .navigate "webpage url"
      .Visible = True
      Do Until IntExpl.readyState = 4
Loop
    '.document.getElementsByName("subAction")(0).Click
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: **1.** The first thing I notice is that you should be using `.getElementsByTagName` (note the 'Tag'). **2.** The next thing I note is that you should be trying to click `.document.getElementsByTagName("input")(0)`

Answer (score 1):

This worked.

Dim IntExpl As Object

```
    Set IntExpl = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


    With IntExpl
          .navigate "https://febontap.victoria.ibm.com/forms/anon/org/notify/guestselection.html?originatingUrl=..%2f..%2f..%2flanding%2forg%2fapp%2ff373ed45-3637-4662-8fb8-a40a0bd621db%2flaunch%2findex.html%3fform%3dF_Form1&guest=..%2fapp%2ff373ed45-3637-4662-8fb8-a40a0bd621db%2flaunch%2findex.html%3fform%3dF_Form1&user=..%2f..%2f..%2fsecure%2forg%2fapp%2ff373ed45-3637-4662-8fb8-a40a0bd621db%2flaunch%2findex.html%3fform%3dF_Form1"
          .Visible = True
          Do Until IntExpl.readyState = 4
    Loop


    .document.getElementsByClassName("lotusBtn")(0).Click



    End With
```